# SQLPLUS IF Function in Select Causes Identifier Too Long Error

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00972

Below select statement causes `ORA-00972: identifier is too long` error. Suspect a syntax error. Running this select to generate a view in SQLPLUS on an Oracle db. Please advise. Thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (CASE WHEN PROCEDURE_CODE IS NULL THEN REVENUE_CODE ELSE PROCEDURE_CODE END)
FROM HEALTH.DATA
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the statement syntactically. Did u try running it without distinct? Also try to reproduce it with help of fiddle or dual statement to give us something to work with

Comment: You lack the alias to that value. When you create a view, all columns must pass the rules of names definitions in Oracle. So basically, what you needed was to add a name to that column.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the `case` expression are useless.

Comment: Curious that you didn't get `ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias` when creating the view. Might have been helpful to show the entire statement you were running, and to have included the full Oracle version.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the problem but maybe my database version is different.

My guess though is adding an alias to your select :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CASE
                   WHEN PROCEDURE_CODE IS NULL THEN
                    REVENUE_CODE
                   ELSE
                    PROCEDURE_CODE
                END) AS THING
  FROM HEALTH.DATA
```

If you don't specify any, it "builds" the column name using the full "CASE" and it might bust some limit there I suppose.

Comment: @Beemer12 Glad it did! You can mark my answer as Accepted so others can quickly find it.

Comment: There is a limit at 30 characters; this limit has been changed to 128 in Oracle 12.2